# ionic 3 browser specific issues in image inside card

Tags: css, ionic3

My code currently looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-slides direction="vertical" speed="1000" slidesPerView="1">
    <ion-slide  class="home-intro"style="background-color:#2298D3">
</ion-slide>
```

**CSS:**

```
.home-intro {
    background: url('http://www.segalpetroniru.com/images/Consulting-Services-Hero-Image-Secondary.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome but in Safari the top part of image gets stripped. Check the example [here](http://moblize.it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `fixed` from the `background` rules in your `CSS`:

```
.home-intro {
    background: url('example.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    ...
}
```